# Pandas.DataFrame filtering by column of strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['trans'] = ['none', 'taxi', 'bus_101', 'bus_105', 'bus_106', 'car', 'horse']
df['cost']  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And I want to filter all the buses out (`'bus_101', 'bus_105', 'bus_106'`)

I tried two ways:

```
df['bus' not in df.trans].trans
```

and tried to get a str out of Series, to compare its first 3 chars:

```
df[df.trans[:3] != 'bus'].trans
```

and

```
df[df.trans.astype(str)[:3] != 'bus'].trans
```

It didn't work out. I'd expect result to be:

```
0       none
1       taxi
5        car
6      horse
```

But all I actually get are errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
df[~df.trans.str.contains('bus')]

   trans  cost
0   none     1
1   taxi     2
5    car     6
6  horse     7
```

Brief explanation:

```
df.trans.str.contains('bus')
```

will check whether `'bus'` is contained in the values of `trans`:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: trans, dtype: bool
```

The negation of it can be done by `~`

```
~df.trans.str.contains('bus')

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
Name: trans, dtype: bool
```

This Boolean series can be passed to `df` to select the desired entries.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame()
df['trans'] = ['none', 'taxi', 'bus_101', 'bus_105', 'bus_106', 'car', 'horse']
df['cost']  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
df[df['trans'].str.contains("bus") == False]

    trans   cost
0   none    1
1   taxi    2
5   car     6
6   horse   7
```